# How to keep multiple database in synchronized state

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a few sites running a php app with a mysql backend. They are all running on separate servers due to the fact that they might not have 100% internet connection time.

Currently, I am storing a modified date time for every record. As well as a flag to mark records as being deleted. Due to the synchronization, all deleted records are still needed to bo tracked so that i can sync the delete.

Every site then tracks when they have synchronized to.

Problem is all the sites does inserts and updates. so if a site is disconnected for a while. it causes problem with the data sync of all the other sites.

Any idea on how to keep all the sites in sync?

The current program that does the sync is written in php. It loops through all the tables and checks for records that has been modified since the last sync.

Comment: Have you ruled out replication?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: If you're not able to set up [mysql replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html), then a script of your own to do whatever duplication is appropriate for your data will be your only other approach, I suspect.  You should really take a look at your application design in general and see how you can make things robust enough to withstand database failure.

Comment: Replication does not work as i have multiple masters. And also the reason the database is designed this way is to tolerate internet failures. replication with multiple sites over bad internet links tend to get some of the updates running in the wrong order.

Comment: It needs to be a general solution. meaning that i cannot tailor a solution for just some scenarios. the sync is part of an in house framework and must work for a lot of general cases.

Comment: The problem you'll have is what happens if I delete a record when connection is lost and you change it... Who wins?  How do you handle these types of collisions?  or worse, we both edit the same record. you change a value to 2 when I want it to be 3....  you get the idea.  Without understanding how this shoudl be handled, there's lots of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: This rarely happens in the environment i am in. there are a lot more insert and deleted then updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. More or less. besides keeping track of when the record was last modified, now i also track when the record was created/modified on the current server. this means that i actually have 2 time stamp. one to track the actual modified time, and one to track when this change has been copied into this server. i just synchronize the records based on the time the record was copied over.